# problem with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

i have a table called users 
this what the table look like

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and finally i have a table called friends, 
this what the table look like

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `friendship_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`friendship_id`),
  KEY `user_id1` (`user_id1`),
  KEY `user_id2` (`user_id2`),
  CONSTRAINT `friends_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id1`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `friends_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id2`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
)
```

so basically if  userA is following userB , then a row will be added to the friends table, with the attribute user_id1 is userA and user_id2 is userB.

im trying to write a mysql query for a searchbox. the user will enter a string and  the query will crawl a list of users that include that string but the people that the user is following need to be displayed first.

so if we have 3 users

- jack
- jason
- john

if the user Chris (who's following jason) enters in the searchbox the string 'ja', the query will crawl the list of users with the following order jason,jack. since jason is followed by chris.

from my understanding , i think it might  a group by problem, i tried different queries but i couldnt get the needed results

do you guys have any idea ?

thanks a lot

Comment: I dont really get your question, do you want to change the order of the results or do you need to give the already existing friendship as the first row? show what query you run to get the users.

Comment: i just wanna crawl users from  the db but i want the friends to be displayed first and then non friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a trick for sorting, so friendships get a 0 and non-friendships get a 1 in a temporary field and then we sort ascending for this field and as second we sort by username

```
SELECT x.username
FROM users x LEFT JOIN friends y ON x.id=y.user_id2 AND y.user_id1=$LOGGED_IN_USER
WHERE LOWER(x.username) LIKE 'ja%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN y.user_id2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,x.username
```

@thanks to scwagner for pointing me to extend JOIN-clause

Comment: in the JOIN be sure to include "and y_user_id1 = $(LoggedInUserId)", otherwise if anyone has a friend that matches the name then you'll sort them to the top.

Comment: thanks for the answer @rabudde
i tried ur query but i didnt work 
here is the error 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE LOWER(t.username) LIKE 'ha%'
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN y.user_id2 IS NULL THEN 1' at line 1

Comment: sorry, there was an `AS order_field` in ORDER BY-clause, please remove it (or see edited answer)

Comment: @rabudde thanks buddy, it works fine now.
thank you for your help 
Cheers